# Can I have an animated profile picture?

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, profile-picture

It seems to be forbidden (based on a meta question) but I don't see that in the Help. If it is, why?

Can this feature be added?

Comment: Yes, that was the effect I wanted: numbers changing, but in the other direction. WHY is it not allowed?

Comment: Then you should probably clarify what do you mean by "animated". Gif or a pic syncing with something?

Comment: I just pasted Nixie2.gif - animated gif from wikipedia - in this profile as an example. It does not count upwards.

Comment: Gifs are de-animated so as it's not potentially annoying.

Comment: I don't think you understand that voting in Meta is different. FR questions with downvotes show that people disagree with your request, not that they necessarily think it's a poorly phrased/researched question.

Comment: @Catija it is poorly phrased by definition if you do not agree with me : )

Comment: That's silly. I've heard some very intelligent arguments for features that I still think are stupid.

Comment: Your question seems to be a [tag:support] question, but you've tagged it [tag:feature-request].. what is it?

Comment: @Catija "tact is the ability to tell someone to go to hell in such a way that they look forward to the trip." My father was a lawyer, and I am an instructor and writer.

Comment: @ᔕᖺᘎᕊ I figured it was disallowed, based on the fact that I have never seen anyone do it.

Comment: Do you think someone with epilepsy and sensitivity to flashing lights would ever agree that flashy, blinky avatars that may send them into a seizure are a good idea? Granted, this is a bit of an overstatement, considering the size... I'm simply making a point that there may be reasons why this is a bad idea.

Comment: @Catija *good* reasons? Someone can disable animation in their browser, if that is an issue for them, right?

Comment: Because we can't have nice things...

Comment: Whether *you* think it's a "good" reason or not is immaterial... I think gifs are annoying and I would never agree to this. Despite your interest in "fun", this is not a site for entertainment.

Comment: "Someone can disable animation in their browser" - wait, how?

Comment: @Catija I guess it is ok for *other people* to have good reasons. What got me in to programming in the first place, 36 years ago, was trying to do new and interesting things.

Comment: @ᔕᖺᘎᕊ really, your edit should say "*may* this feature be added?" I am sure that it CAN be.

Comment: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/271938/animated-gif-as-avatar

Comment: @nicael Thank you for the link, I *did* search and look at the Help first. But I still think it should be left to the discretion of users. Surely there is already a way in place to "police" inappropriate profile pics? It would cover this case also.

Comment: @nocomprende no, it's 'can this feature be added, with the consent and support from the community?' which is a 'no'.

Answer (score 24):

[image]

Comment: Question: is this your standard response for meta questions now?

Comment: [Also appropriate.](https://media.giphy.com/media/12XMGIWtrHBl5e/giphy.gif)

Comment: @FlagAsSpam It should be, by gum.

Comment: @MartinBüttner or [some RLM](http://i.stack.imgur.com/0SBWN.gif)

Comment: @Won't That one's gross. :c I still prefer "Ah hell naw!". It seems more to the point.

Comment: [Another one](http://stream1.gifsoup.com/view5/2654439/man-falling-off-of-a-cliff-o.gif).