# Animated avatars in user profile and newsletter

Tags: bug, status-completed, profile-page, profile-picture, newsletter

First, to make it clear Stack Exchange does not allow animated avatars, the [Can I have an animated profile picture?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/272911/can-i-have-an-animated-profile-picture) feature request has been declined by SE staff back in 2016.

However, as of today, users who upload animated gif as avatar have the animation showing in their profile, e.g. [this user](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2827296/oliver-ni). (on all sites)

Can this please be fixed, or if there was policy change, can the above feature request be changed to [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed) instead?

Note, this also affects the newsletter, which show the animation in the email, and this can become pretty irritating.

Comment: Fortunately, the animation works only on their profile and not on Q&A pages ...

Comment: @Glorfindel yeah, but who knows... if that specific thumbnail is broken, other might break as well without notice.

Comment: I vote for disabling animated profiles consistently. The profile-pic and post-pic should *not* have two different behaviors.

Comment: @RobertCartaino that is not technically possible, I'm afraid. SE is relying on imgur to disable the animation by creating smaller versions of the uploaded image (called "thumbnails"), which have no animation, then use those thumbnails all around, by adding the `?s=[number]` to the URL of the original image. But now looks like a problem in imgur side cause them to serve the original image instead of the thumbnail version, hence the animation. The bug is likely on imgur side, but SE has the means to contact and poke imgur to fix it.

Comment: Interestingly enough this only happens on the full site. The app and the mobile site show a static image even on the profile page (iOS).

Comment: I'm not sure I want this fixed...

Comment: I like the idea of an animation **only in the profile**. It would be distracting **anywhere else**, but in the profile I kind of like it.

Comment: only vaguely related, as it is a bug in how imgur handles things - I like the fact that my avatar looks different at different sizes :-)

Comment: As far as I can see, any [question about relation between SO and imgur](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/314028/the-stack-imgur-service-is-no-longer-resizing-images-correctly#comment1054852_314028) to SO employees leads to completely silence. Maybe @RobertCartaino can answer to break my assumption? I've asked ruSO community manager in chat, but with no results as expected.

Comment: @älёxölüt CM has little chance to know about those things in detail. Only developers who work with code related to imgur can probably really know. And Shog. ;-)

Comment: @ShadowWizard I don’t want any details, just a general resolution, for instance: “we asked imgur, they said wait 6-8 weeks to fix” or “we’re planning to switch from imgur to home brewed service”. But now I see NO ANSWER at all. Just silence.

Comment: @älёxölüt Well... Took me many years to accept the fact that many times that is the situation and that it doesn't mean they don't care. They just have different priorities and their own time line to do things. We should not take it personally. :)

Comment: Hence they should add “don’t” [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/13016/339911).

Comment: FYI from [comment in 2013](https://meta.stackexchange.com/posts/comments/472868): "*I'm afraid we're not going to support animated gifs. The ability to upload them was a bug that has been fixed.*"

Comment: @SonictheIntrovertedHedgehog heh. Either he was wrong to begin with, or this has changed at some point. But I am 1000% sure we could upload animated gifs to SE imgur and they kept the animation for **years**.

Comment: Not sure that 100 (or place any other value here) reps is enough for bounty ... when only the employee can answer.

Comment: @älёxölüt of course not, even 10000000 won't be enough. Old habits dies hard, I'm not expecting the bounty will actually draw any official attention. :)

Comment: Just edit your post and then revert to the previos revision for the [edit removed during grace period] record. I don't think that such behavour is forbidden on SE.

Comment: @älёxölüt sorry not sure what you mean. If you mean bumping with useless edit then it is forbidden and I consider it as abuse of edit privilege.

Comment: @ShadowWizard what kind of bumping is forbidden? No one is insured from making the wrong edit and rolback it. Nobody can confirm that my edit was made for the reason of bumping.

Comment: @älёxölüt this can work one or two times, but when it happens more than that, it is obvious what's going on.

Comment: Are there questions where you've offer a bounty more than twice?

Comment: @älёxölüt not sure, with hundreds of bounties, I lost track long ago. I just offer on a whim, usually.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So... this looks like it was actually caused by the same server outage that was making it so that [image resizing wasn't working as it should](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/314028/the-stack-imgur-service-is-no-longer-resizing-images-correctly). So, when that was fixed, this was also fixed... YAY! Uploading a gif now should behave as expected.

I briefly uploaded the same gif from that user's profile to my own and it became a static image. If you want to check for yourself, it's worth noting that when I tested it out, the preview looks like a gif but after you actually save your settings, the resulting image on a profile page is static.

Unfortunately, it has the same side effect... content uploaded during that window is the way it is, so removing the gifs now would require the user re-upload the image.

Comment: Are moderators able to replace animated avatars in case the user refuses to? (IIRC animated avatars are against policy, and a prior case where it was allowed was deemed a bug and fixed.)

Comment: As with any profile image or username, moderators can always reset to the default when they feel it's appropriate.

Comment: PNG animations still work; I’m sending you a profile with an example.