# Profile pictures on the profile page shouldn't be stretched

Tags: bug, profile-page, images, profile-picture

It looks like there's been a [recent change](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/322457) in the profile picture system. However, that appears to have broken images which are not squares.

This is what I see on my profile page. It's horizontally stretched, and it looks quite ugly:

> [image]

For comparison, here's the top bar, which looks fine.

> [image]

I've seen other peoples' pictures which are stretched vertically presumably their pictures have landscape-oriented originals, while mine is in a portrait configuration.

I'm on Chrome 71.0.3578.98 for Windows 10.

Comment: TL;DR: imgur stopped creating thumbnail versions for some sizes, the profile page avatar happens to be one of the victims.

Comment: @ShadowWizard It seems related, but that doesn't appear to say much about how the top bar is still fine. Do you think fixing the size of the file will solve the stretching problem? I'm afraid I'm not completely sure about how that whole system works... If they're the same issue, I'll mark the suggested question as a duplicate.

Comment: Yes, same issue... each place use a different thumbnail image. So far only the one used for profile page avatar (should be 328x328 pixels, see the URL of [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aQtfD.jpg?s=328&g=1)) is broken and giving the original image instead, which also leads to animated avatars.