# Imgur feature allows animated avatars

Tags: bug, profile-picture

Established Stack Exchange policy and the existing community consensus is that animated avatars are not permitted, as discussed in:

- [Are animated GIFs allowed as avatars?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/389316/13253010)
- [Can I have an animated profile picture?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/272911/1272872)
- [Animated Gif Profile pic on StackOverflow doesn't animate](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/164023/1272872)
- [Is it possible for us to use an animated GIF as our profile picture or in our personal information?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/288711/1272872)

I had been abusing a feature of Imgur to have an animated avatar. Yesterday, the moderators reset my avatar and clarified that animated avatars are not permitted. The policy about this is a bit unclear, my case was discussed further in [this post](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/421458/13253010).

For context, SE sites prevent animated avatars by adding some parameters to the Imgur image URLs, from this:

```
https://i.stack.imgur.com/79Jch.gif
```

To this:

```
https://i.stack.imgur.com/79Jch.gif?s=256&g=1
```

This is an Imgur feature that will resize the image and make gifs static, but there is a legacy feature described in [this Imgur API documentation](https://api.imgur.com/models/image) that will override those parameters, by adding a suffix to the end of the image id, and before the file extension.

For example, adding `m` to the URL will make the gif no longer static:

```
https://i.stack.imgur.com/79Jchm.gif?s=256&g=1
```

I understand that this problem is on the Imgur side, but this could be prevented from the SE side, simply by removing/blocking these suffix characters at the end of the image ID: `[s, b, t, m, l, h]`.

Update: [@starball](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/997587/starball) has made an [SEDE query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1671083) of profiles that abused this to have animated avatars.

Comment: Seems this trick fixes [the problem introduced for transparent avatars](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/369349). I'd be sad to see that taken away. Hopefully we do get something about transparency eventually.

Comment: To address [this comment you made](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/posts/comments/933887) that "_SE has no bug report award_", now you see that you can get sweet ✨ _fake internet points_ ✨ on meta :)  also note that if you find a _security vulnerability_, there is a [hall of fame](https://stackexchange.com/about/security).

Comment: Thanks for divulging your method. I was the first to flag you, having noticed you in the review queues. It's not personal! To the contrary, I'm glad to see another newly active user helping make the internet a better place (though I do think you can slow down in the queues and focus on _quality_ of reviews rather than quantity- especially now that you already have your steward badge). I highly recommend reading [the FAQs on doing the review queues](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/155538/what-are-the-guidelines-for-reviewing).

Comment: @VLAZ there is another trick that allows transparency, I have thought of including it in this post but it seems irrelevant so I decided not to.